# Enforcing security on broadcast receiver without access to calling package

Tags: java, android, security, broadcastreceiver

I've been working on an android app that receives intents from several known applications. My question is whether there is any way to get the calling package when the BroadcastReceiver receives the intent?

The situation is that I don't have access to the calling package and cannot manipulate the package manifest in any way. I am familiar with enforcing security by using a signature or permission to call the receiver but that isn't possible in this instance.

Is there any way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

may not be an elegant solution but you start a logcat filter in your code and start listening for sending broadcast events, you can retreive package information from that.